# Set Copy to Output folder by code

Tags: c#, project, buildengine

I am developing a code generation tool, so the project files(.csprj) are created by code.
Is there any way to mark a content file to be copied always to the output directory? 
 ...

```
var project = new BuildEngine.Project();
project.Load(ProjectFile.FullName, ProjectLoadSettings.IgnoreMissingImports);
var buildItem = project.AddNewItem("Content", fileName);
```

... I need something like this  `buildItem.CopyToOutput=true`...

```
project.Save(ProjectFile.FullName);
```

Every ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
buildItem.SetMetadata("CopyToOutputDirectory", "Always");
```

Comment: Better answer.  Didn't realize BuildEngine was part of .Net.

Comment: PreserveNewest instead of Always If you want to preserve the newest

Answer (score 0):

```
<Content Include="My.File">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```