# Set "Build Action" and "Copy to output directory"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

Is there a way to set these  "Build Action" and "Copy to output directory"  properties from code?

Comment: Are you implementing a VS extension?

Comment: Yes, but these are a properties of a file xaml that I generate in run time. So I should set these properties  programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Copy to Output folder by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032430/set-copy-to-output-folder-by-code)

Comment: It seems the right solution, but I have some errors becouse it doesn't recognize the method "AddItem" of my object "Project"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference VSLangProj, look up property names from the `FileProperties2` class, [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.fileproperties2.aspx).
To obtain and change properties of a file, use

```
var project = _applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
var items = project.ProjectItems;
var item = items.Item(1);
var property = item.Properties.Item("BuildAction");
property.Value = prjBuildAction.prjBuildActionCompile;
```

To define the build action, set the [BuildAction property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb2506d2.aspx) to one of these values:

- prjBuildActionCompile
- prjBuildActionContent
- prjBuildActionEmbeddedResource
- prjBuildActionNone

The [CopyToOutputDirectory property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.fileproperties2.copytooutputdirectory.aspx) is an uint, and can be set to one of these `__COPYTOOUTPUTSTATE` values ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.__copytooutputstate.aspx)):

- 0 ... `Never`
- 1 ... `Always`
- 2 ... `PreserveNewest`

This answer assumes that you are developing an extension to Visual Studio. There is another answer which achieves the same using the build engine: [Set Copy to Output folder by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032430/set-copy-to-output-folder-by-code).

Comment: Ok this is right solution, but How can set copy to output = Copy if Newer?

Comment: they documented the possible values for CopyToOutputDirectory elsewhere > updated answer.

Comment: var propertyCopyToOutput = item.Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory");

            propertyCopyToOutput.Value = "PreserveNewest"  
It's correct?

Comment: Anyway I receive an ArgumentException to var property = item.Properties.Item("BuildAction"); ..

Comment: not all properties are defined on all files and may depend on project type as well. for the copytooutputdirectory, the numeric values 1,2 or 3 should be assigned - the underlying property is a `uint`